# change selected value dropdown reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm using a dropdown box with ReactJS and I'm using the default values that I get from "this.state.whoIsChecked.allowDestroyAll". But when I use it as default value, I can't change the value anymore. Here follows the code I'm using:

```
<select 
className="form-control" 
id="ada" 
value={this.state.whoIsChecked.allowDestroyAll}>
    <option>true</option>
    <option>false</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This is extremely vague. Please try providing more context.

Comment: This is already answered on different thread. Please look into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29108779/how-to-get-selected-value-of-a-dropdown-menu-in-reactjs

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get selected value of a dropdown menu in ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29108779/how-to-get-selected-value-of-a-dropdown-menu-in-reactjs)

Comment: Please check out the seemingly duplicate question above, if you believe this is not a duplicate then add more detail to your post outlining your problem and what you have tried that has not worked.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an `onChange` event with the `controlled input` and update the state in order to change the value after providing a value to Option field like

```
handleChange(e) {
     var whoIsChecked = {...this.state.whoIsChecked}
     whoIsChecked.allowDestroyAll = e.target.value
     this.setState({whoIsChecked})
}


render( ) {
 return <select 
    className="form-control" 
    id="ada" 
    onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e)}
    value={this.state.whoIsChecked.allowDestroyAll}>
        <option value="true">true</option>
        <option value="false">false</option>
    </select>
}
```

```js
class App extends React.Component {
state= {
    whoIsChecked: {
        allowDestroyAll: "true"
    }
}
handleChange(e) {
         var whoIsChecked = {...this.state.whoIsChecked}
         whoIsChecked.allowDestroyAll = e.target.value
         this.setState({whoIsChecked}, ()=> {console.log(this.state)})
         
    }
    

    render( ) {
     return <select 
        className="form-control" 
        id="ada" 
        onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e)}
        value={this.state.whoIsChecked.allowDestroyAll}>
            <option value="true">true</option>
            <option value="false">false</option>
        </select>
    }
    
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Consider accepting and upvoting the answer if it helped

Answer (score 1):

You are using the [controlled element](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components), using the value property (means controlling the value of `selectfield` by the `state` variable), you need to define the `onchange` method to update that `state` value otherwise `selectfield` will become **read-only**.

Write it like this:

```
<select 
    className="form-control" 
    id="ada" 
    value={this.state.whoIsChecked.allowDestroyAll}
    onChange={this.change}
>
    <option value='true'>true</option>
    <option value='false'>false</option>
</select>

change = (e) => {
    let whoIsChecked = Object.assign({}, this.state.whoIsChecked)
    whoIsChecked.allowDestroyAll = e.target.value;
    this.setState({whoIsChecked});
}
```

**Note:** You need to assign the unique value to each `option`.