# Select value not changed on state update ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drop-down-menu

I have no idea how to fix this thing
have been spent more than an hours to solve this problem
but none of the solution fix this

So i have a combo box (Select tag element) which i would like to change the value when a modal box is opened.

**I have already implement defaultValue to set the value of the combobox but it won't change. However on other input such as the notes / amount it can get the defaultValue and set it to the element.**

*I have try to debug the this.currState.deposit_type_id and i get the right value*

But in fact it won't change

it always refer to the default value

I have made several type of this thing but none of them has ever had this bug

Here's the screenshot for the code and the image

[image: These are the code to pass the data from parent's component, and deposit type for all the value i will put on the combo box]

This is the code to pass the data from parent's component, and deposit type for all the value i will put on the combo box

[image]

This is the code that i used for set the default value when the modal box is opened

[image]

This is the result, it supposed to choose "Kas Besar", yet it choose "Deposit Type" instead

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get selected value of a dropdown menu in ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29108779/how-to-get-selected-value-of-a-dropdown-menu-in-reactjs)

Comment: @mersocarlin yea i know bout that thing, i have already implement that, but the dropdown itself won't change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure as I am not able to try it now but you could try to add your value argument for input's html like this:

```
value={ this.state.currData && this.state.currData.deposit_type_id  }
```

But it would be better to get currData from props. So `this.props.currData`.

Comment: as far as i know we're not allowed to use value to set for the value, we should use defaultValue

Comment: You can use value, see https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#the-select-tag

Comment: But you should not use your props in state like you did in componentWillMount. Use props in render function and initialize state in constructor function.

Comment: But i need the value from my props to set the value on my state. Can i do that in my constructor? Get the props then set the state on constructor

Comment: Why do you need it that way?

Comment: I want to set the props to the state so i can use that for the data i will send from the form

Comment: Just pass the props. No need to move them to state.

Comment: it works ! Just to make it clear, your answer is to validate first whether currData is null or not, if it is not null then give the deposit_type_id?

so what's the difference between value and defaultValue? As i have read, default value used to set initial value while value to set the value to the props